# SimpleDateFormat problems with 2 year date

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I'm trying to understand two things:

1. Why doesn't the following code throw an exception (since the `SimpleDateFormat` is not lenient)
2. It doesn't throw an exception, but why is it parsing the year as 0013 (instead of [using the rules here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#year) the +80:-20 years from today rule)

Here's the code

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class TestDate {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        format.setLenient(false);
        Date date = format.parse("01/01/13"); // Since this only has a 2 digit year, I would expect an exception to be thrown

        System.out.println(date); // Prints Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 13

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);

        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)); // Prints 13
    }
}
```

If it makes a difference, I'm using java 1.6.0_38-b05 on Ubuntu

Comment: FYI, the `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat` classes seen here are now obsolete, having been supplanted by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. See the modern solution in the [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62268967/642706).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SimpleDateFormat API:

*For parsing, if the number of pattern letters is more than 2, the year is interpreted literally, regardless of the number of digits. So using the pattern "MM/dd/yyyy", "01/11/12" parses to Jan 11, 12 A.D.*

As for lenient, when it's set to false parse throws exception for invalid dates, eg 01/32/12, while in lenient mode this date is treated as 02/01/12. SimpleDateFormat uses Calendar internally, details about leniency can be found in Calendar API.

Answer (score 3):

**Question 1.** This is a partial duplicate of [Why Does Java's SimpleDateFormat parse this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564570/why-does-javas-simpledateformat-parse-this). The second answer on the question answers this nicely. The crux of it is this:

**Number:** For parsing, the number of pattern letters is ignored unless it's needed to separate two adjacent fields. 
**Year:** During parsing, only strings consisting of exactly two digits […] will be parsed into the default century. Any other numeric string, such as a one digit string, a three or more digit string, or a two digit string that isn't all digits (for example, "-1"), is interpreted literally. So "01/02/3" or "01/02/003" are parsed, using the same pattern

**Question 2.** Look carefully: your input format is not the same as the format that you are passing to the function.

`new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");`

vs.

`format.parse("01/01/13");`

Either parse to `01/01/2013` or use the date forat `'dd/MM/yy'`.

Comment: It should throw an exception, since lenient is set to false, and we only want to parse a 4 year date.

Comment: Sorry that my answer was seen as unhelpful. I have edited it, and taken a shot at the first part of the question as well.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [SimpleDateFormat javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for JDK 1.6,

> For parsing, the number of pattern letters is ignored unless it's
>   needed to separate two adjacent fields.

A look at the source code for the method that does the work, `SimpleDateFormat.parse(String, ParsePosition)`, confirms this.  There is a variable `obeyCount` that is true if the pattern has no delimiters, like "yyyyMMdd", and false otherwise. With your pattern the parser looks for 3 numbers separated by 2 delimiters and does not care about the number of digits in each position.

The answers to your questions:

1. `Lenient` is not a factor when delimiters are used.
2. You did not call [`SimpleDateFormat.set2DigitYearStart`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#set2DigitYearStart%28java.util.Date%29) so why should the code do what you didn't tell it to do?

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, and the exception you expected comes sure thing:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String strToParse = "01/01/13";
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(strToParse, dateFormatter);
```

Result:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '01/01/13' could not be parsed at index 6
>   at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2046)
>   at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
>   at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:428)
> ```

If you scroll right, you will see that the exception message mentions “could not be parsed at index 6”. Index 6 in the string is where the two digit year stands where four digits were expected.

When this question was asked nearly 7 years ago, using `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` was acceptable. They were always poorly designed, and their replacement came out 7 months after the question was asked, so they are now considered long outdated. I warmly recommend using java.time instead.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.