# setLenient(false) let pass validation on date format

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I'm trying to validate date format with a code below

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
    String dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    String dateToValidate = "18-12-18";

    if(!isThisDateValid(dateToValidate,dateFormat)){
        System.out.println("Date is invalid");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Date is valid");
    }
    }


       public static boolean isThisDateValid(String dateToValidate, String dateFromat){

        if(dateToValidate == null){
            return false;
        }

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFromat);
        sdf.setLenient(false);

        try {
            Date date = sdf.parse(dateToValidate);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

but instead failing it let it pass.

Test code available here: https://ideone.com/ryN7HO

Any thoughts?

Comment: The year 18 is perfectly valid. Did you expect it to require zero filled digits? Add a check for `dateToValidate.matches("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}")`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I expect that it will validate for full year number like `2018`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch you can post it as an answer. It did the job

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SimpleDateFormat problems with 2 year date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18127845/simpledateformat-problems-with-2-year-date)

Comment: I have not tested, but I think that [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) solve this out of the box. They are also generally much nicer to work with. `SimpleDateFormat` is both outdated and troublesome.

Comment: I suspect that what you really want to validate is not the format, but whether the date is within range. If I am correct, set an earliest date that could possibly be correct in your program, and similarly a latest date, and check that the actual date is within the range. If the range doesn’t include year 18, this will be rejected, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The year 18 is a valid year, `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't enforce a particular pattern (and will not require zero filled values). However, you can add a check for your *pattern* with a regular expression. Four digits, a dash, two digits, a dash and two digits. Like,

```
if (!dateToValidate.matches("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}")) {
    return false;
}
```

**Note**: This code is not Y10k compliant.

Comment: "Y10k" ROFL --- True, though. Not BC compliant either.

Comment: I don't think they had ISO standards and RFCs in Roman times :-)